# divs height issue with chrome 'save as pdf'

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf

I have a simple web page with 3 divs

```
.power-bar-3 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 3px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #bababa;
}
.power-force-3 {
    width: 63px; 
    height: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000000;
}

<div class="power-bar-3"><div class="power-force-3"></div></div>
<div class="power-bar-3"><div class="power-force-3"></div></div>
<div class="power-bar-3"><div class="power-force-3"></div></div>
```

[image]

from chrome, I save the web page as a pdf file and this is the result I get:

[image]

As you can see, in the pdf file, the div's height are not the same. The first and the last line are thinner. Do you know why and how can I fix this ? thanks

Comment: What are you using to save it as a pdf?

Comment: from google chrome...file->print->save as pdf